# Retrieving Excel data from OneDrive using Graph API v5.31 in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, excel, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

How can I retrieve columns/rows and their cell values from a spreadsheet on OneDrive using Graph API v5.31 in .NET?
Recently I updated Graph Nuget package from v4 to v5, I never had any issues with the old version, but the new one brought in a lot of changes which required me to refactor my code.

I managed to get most of the things working, I just struggle to figure out how to retrieve values from a spreadsheet.

The Excel file I am accessing is shared with me. I don't think it matters though cause I managed to access and read the file, it's just that I can't get any cell values.

Code could do with some extra refactoring as it is not async but that's something I'll address another time.

My old v4 implementation looked more or less as follows:

```
var driveBuilder = GraphClient.Sites[$"{site},{siteId}"].Drive;
var wbBuilder = driveBuilder.List.Items[listItemId].DriveItem.Workbook;
var range = wbBuilder.Worksheets[sheetName].UsedRange(true).Column(index).Request().GetAsync().Result
```

Then I used ArrayEnumerator to get all the values for a column.

For v5 I have this test code so far:

```
WorkbookRange usedRange = GraphClient.Drives[driveId].Items[itemId].Workbook.Worksheets[sheetName].UsedRange.GetAsync().Result;
WorkbookRange colRange = GraphClient.Drives[driveId].Items[itemId].Workbook.Worksheets[sheetName].RangeWithAddress("NAME!A1:A79").GetAsync().Result;
WorkbookRange cell = GraphClient.Drives[driveId].Items[itemId].Workbook.Worksheets[sheetName].CellWithRowWithColumn(2, 2).GetAsync().Result;
```

I know that it reads the worksheet as I can see correct values for cell count, row count and column count when debugging, but I have no idea how to get cell values or individual columns and rows. I checked both 'Values' and 'Text' properties and they just hold this:

```
{"AdditionalData":{},"BackingStore":{"InitializationCompleted":true,"ReturnOnlyChangedValues":false},"OdataType":null}
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/kiota/issues/2319) is a blocker. SDK v5 using Kiota for generating the client code and Kiota doesn't handle json object returned by almost all workbook endpoints. Hope they will fixed it soon.